# Apple iTunes Connect app status, waiting for upload

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted my app to the Apple app store successfully through Xcode, but in iTunes Connect the status of my app is still "Waiting For Upload". Do I need to take action? My deadline for submission is nigh...

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does "submit through Xcode" mean you uploaded the binary?  And have you tried reloading the web page after a minute?

Comment: Thanks for reading. Somehow I missed the actual upload. I Verified, but glossed over the upload part somehow *cough!*. Duh. Was a bit grueling and confusing process.

Answer (score 1):

The process of uploading an app can be a bit daunting the first (few!) times...

1. Create the app on iTunesConnect
2. Fill out ALL of the meta data about the app
3. Press the button "Upload Binary" in the top right hand corner of that edit screen in iTunesConnect. You should get an email confirming this
4. Go into XCode.
5. Archive the app by going to Product > Archive. (If this is greyed out, you need to change the target to an iOS device, from the Simulator.
6. Follow the steps in the wizard to distribute the app to the App Store. You upload the app to iTunesConnect through XCode.

Comment: issue is new itunes released design everthing changed in that itunes staus is not changing

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In iTunes Connect in the 'App Summary' page you need to hit this button before you can upload anything via Xcode.

Comment: itunesconnect change everything..this is old itunes check itunes noe?